# OpenDNS-like 404 page in home network

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2

People who use OpenDNS and go to a non-existing domain are getting a [nice fancy search page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evk3e.png) telling them that the domain doesn't exists instead of the browser error page.

Here in my home network we have a Windows 2008 R2 server with the DNS role enabled.

Is there any way to make my own fancy looking error page to show up at all computers when they enter a domain not found by the local DNS server and the forwarders / root hints servers?

Comment: Bleh. Those things are evil. I prefer getting a real lookup failure message that I can parse in my scripting rather than a redirect. I don't want funky DNS redirects and wild cards messing with my otherwise stable services and automated routines.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's a violation of RFC to return results that do not exist. While some users think the "fancy search page" is nice; the tin-hat folk would complain of privacy violations, browser hijacking, censorship, cross-site scripting vulnerabilities, and similar violations of the trust we put in the Internet's core infrastructure systems.

I don't believe Windows Server's DNS server is natively capable of DNS Hijacking. BIND and DJDNS are. You can find [directions for BIND](http://lost-and-found-narihiro.blogspot.com/2011/10/bind-99-alpha-2-nx-domain-redirection.html), and the [BIND Binaries for Windows](https://www.isc.org/software/bind) on the net. You'll need to setup a server that accepts these redirected requests, IIS can do this (you may want to install URL Rewrite as well, to make it clear that the user has been redirected)

Comment: Thanks, I don't really care about violating a RFC, it's just for a home network. My mom, dad or sister don't mind having a fancy error page. Will look into BIND/DJDNS. I guess Apache can also be used to accept the redirected request?

Comment: While it frustrates me to no end that people don't care about the RFCs, they are literally why the Internet works and if everyone took that attitude with them the Internet would be the networks CompuServe and AOL built in the 80-90s... Yes, Apache works just as well (if not better) than IIS.